# CSS full screen website page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a full screen website that has on the right a fullscreen image and on the left an vertical menu and a logo.

The html & css code that I managed to build so far is this, but I do not know how to make the whole website to be fullscreen:

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>ella - Organizator de evenimente</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="page">   

        <header>
        <img src="imagini/logo.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="logo ella organizator de evenimente">
        </header>

        <nav>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Despre</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Servicii</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Galerie</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <footer>
            <a href="#"><img class="social" src="imagini/Facebook.png" width="32" height="32" alt="poza facebook" ></a>
            <a href="#"><img class="social" src="imagini/LinkedIn.png" width="32" height="32" alt="poza linkedin"></a>
            <a href="#"><img class="social" src="imagini/Twitter.png" width="32" height="32" alt="poza twitter"></a>
            <a href="#"><img class="social" src="imagini/Google+.png" width="32" height="32" alt="poza google+"></a>
        <p>&copy; 2014 Chițu Ștefan</p>
        </footer>

        <aside>
        <img src="imagini/poza-dreapta.jpg" width="512" height="658" alt="poza dreapta">
        <h1>Fericirea autentică nu are vârstă ...</h1>
        </aside>

</div>


</body>

</html>
```

&

CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

html, body {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0px;
   background-color: #fff;
}

#page {
    position: relative;
}
#page header img {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    left: 180px;
    top:68px;
}

#page nav {
    font-size: 21px;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #0c0c0c;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    left: 222px;
    top: 267px;
}

ul
{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    font-size: 21px;
}

ul li a, ul li a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0c0c0c;
}

ul li a:hover, ul li .current {
    color: #F00;
    text-decoration: none;
}

aside {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    left: 700px;
}

#page aside img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}

footer {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    left: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 600px;
    font-size: 14,6px;
}

h1 {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 340px;
    left: 20px;
    font-size: 34px;
    color: #0c0c0c;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

**[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dvDmZ/)**

Comment: @VedantTerkar Are you going to tell your users to press f11? - OP - https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/domref/fullscreen.html

Comment: @Mr.Alien i was joking.. i mentioned a link in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
var fullscreen = false;    
var viewFullScreen = document.getElementById("fullscreen");
     var exitFullScreen = document.getElementById("roadmap-fullscreen-exit-button");
     addFullscreenEventListener(viewFullScreen);
     addFullscreenEventListener(exitFullScreen);
        function addFullscreenEventListener(elem){
          if (elem) {
            elem.addEventListener("click", function () {
              if(fullscreen){
                var docElm = document.documentElement;
                if (docElm.requestFullscreen) {
                    docElm.requestFullscreen();
                }
                else if (docElm.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                    docElm.mozRequestFullScreen();
                }
                else if (docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
                    docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen();
                }
              }else{
                 if (document.exitFullscreen) {
                    document.exitFullscreen();
                }
                else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
                    document.mozCancelFullScreen();
                }
                else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
                    document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
                }
              }
            }, false);
        }
        }
```

HTML

You can use the following anchor tag. On click of this will your site go fullscreen

```
<a href="#" id="fullscreen">Fullscreen</a>
```